# get current date in SQL query in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda

I am writing a method in lambda using node.js and I have SQL Query in that method and I want current time so I will get that

here is my query I am using in that function

```
let sql =`UPDATE ctrData2.Tag SET Name=?, Description=?, UpdatedBy=?, UpdatedDate= now() WHERE TagId=?`;
```

SO what is the right way to get the current time?

Comment: What issue are you seeing?

Comment: Your query seems right

Comment: I don't know but now it's working :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript has Date object for working with dates:

```
let now = new Date();
```

This gives you the current Date, e.g.

```
Tue Jul 07 2020 10:42:56 GMT+0300 (East Africa Time)
```

Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for the various ways you can manipulate Date objects.